# Jenkinsfile: How to get the trigger of a build

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I'm trying to figure out how to determine what caused a build to run from inside a scripted Jenkinsfile.  The reason is that I have a script in a docker container that I want to run on a cron job, so when the cron job triggers, I just want it to run the container, but when I push changes, I want it check out the code, rebuild the container, run static code analysis, run tests, etc.  There's no need for all of that on a cron run.

How can I get the cause?  I tried `currentBuild.getCauses()`, but I get

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.steps.build.RunWrapper.getCauses() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
```

I tried `println currentBuild.getRawBuild().getCauses()`, but got

```
org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: Scripts not permitted to use method org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.steps.build.RunWrapper getRawBuild
```

How cna i get the cause of a build in my jenkinsfile?

Comment: I had this problem and found two ways to work around it: 1) go to Manage Jenkins and then In Process Script Approval and approve that call, or 2) put the command into a function in a library that either does all the work you need or returns a string or array or whatever of the build causes. `currentBuild.getCauses()` doesn't exist (I assume) and `currentBuild.getRawBuild().getCauses()` exists but is blocked by security. It took me awhile to structure a library correctly but most of the info is here https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/

Comment: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-41272 is open fort supporting this.

Comment: Take a look [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-examples/blob/master/pipeline-examples/get-build-cause/getBuildCause.groovy).

Comment: @JoaoVitorino I can't use that in the Jenkinsfile. See the details in the question

Answer (score 2):

This Groovy code will get the name of the triggering project (and it runs fine in the Groovy sandbox):

```java
String getTriggeringProjectName() {
    if (currentBuild.upstreamBuilds) {
        return currentBuild.upstreamBuilds[0].projectName
    } else {
        return ""
    }
}
```

Comment: This is by far the best solution, not needing to approve scripts that have security vulnerabilities is a huge plus

Answer (score 1):

```
manager.build.causes
```

for use, you will need to approve these signatures

```
method org.jvnet.hudson.plugins.groovypostbuild.GroovyPostbuildRecorder$BadgeManager getBuild
method hudson.model.Run getCauses
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

The project name of the triggering build ([getUpstreamProject](https://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Cause.UpstreamCause.html#getUpstreamProject--)) and the build number ([getUpstreamBuild](https://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Cause.UpstreamCause.html#getUpstreamBuild--)):

```
currentBuild.rawBuild.getCauses().get(0).getUpstreamProject()
currentBuild.rawBuild.getCauses().get(0).getUpstreamBuild()
```

Or another way that I think might not need permissions changes:
[currentBuild.getUpstreamBuilds().get(0).getProjectName()](https://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/AbstractBuild.html#getUpstreamBuilds--)

I needed the upstream project's branch in something I'm working on:

```
currentBuild.getUpstreamBuilds().get(0).getRawBuild().getEnvVars().get("BRANCH_NAME", "")
```

Here's the docs on that: [getEnvVars()](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/hudson/model/Run.html#getEnvVars--)

You'll have to enable a mess of permissions, by the way.