# How does jenkins create multiple build triggers in a task, with different steps for each build trigger

Tags: jenkins, cicd

I want multiple build triggers to be created in a task, and the steps for each build trigger to be different

in a task, I want to have three triggers, three different steps

```
1、Common build     setp 1 - setp3
2、Timing build      setp 4 - setp7
3、Specified rule construction   setp 8 - setp11
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a function that runs before the stages do which gets the reason for the build trigger. An example of this can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64344218/3730626). You could then have a set of env variables such as COMMON_BUILD = true/false, TIMING_BUILD = true/false depending on the result of the function.

Before each stage you could then add a `when` condition ([docs](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#when)). So for example you could could put steps 1 - 3 in one stage and only run that stage when COMMON_BUILD == true:

```
stage('1-3') {
  when {
    expression {
        return env.COMMON_BUILD
    }
  }
  steps {
    ...
  }
}
```